# converting javascript code to take image instead of emoji

Tags: javascript, web, emoji

I have some code that displays an emoji to a page as part of an animal sound guessing game website. I noticed the emojis display as black and white with some not displaying at all on the computers where this website would be mostly used(really old large touch screen tv computers). I want to convert it to use images instead of emoji. but can't get it to work.

```
const $canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    $things = document.getElementById('things'),
    animals=['','',''];

    $audioTag = document.getElementById('audio'),
    soundsUrls = {
    wrong: './sounds/wronganswer.mp3',
    correct: './sounds/rightanswer.mp3',
   
    animals: {
      who: './sounds/who.mp3',
      '': './sounds/dog.mp3',
      '': './sounds/cat.mp3',
      '': './sounds/gorilla.mp3' 
    
    }
};

const playSound = (things, sound) => {
    $audioTag.src = soundsUrls[things][sound];
    $audioTag.play();
   
};
const playSounds = (animal) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        playSound($things.value, animal);
    }, 4000)
}

const selectedAnswer = ($event) => {

    const isLiElement = $event.target.localName === "li";
    if (!isLiElement) { return false; }

    const currentSelectedAnswer = $event.target.dataset.id;
    const correctAnswer = $canvas.dataset.answer;

    const isPlayButton = $event.target.dataset.id === 'play-sound';
    if (isPlayButton) {
        return playSounds(correctAnswer);
    }


    if (currentSelectedAnswer === correctAnswer) {
        $canvas.classList.add('correct');

        $audioTag.src = soundsUrls.correct;
        $audioTag.play();

        setTimeout(() => {
            $canvas.classList.remove('correct');
            createLevel();
        }, 1300);

    } else {
        $canvas.classList.add('wrong');

        $audioTag.src = soundsUrls.wrong;
        $audioTag.play();

        setTimeout(() => {
            playSound($things.value, currentSelectedAnswer);
        }, 1100);

        setTimeout(() => {
            $canvas.classList.remove('wrong');
        }, 1300);
    }
}

const shuffle = (animalArray) => {
    let counter = animalArray.length;
    while (counter > 0) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
        counter--;
        let temp = animalArray[counter];
        animalArray[counter] = animalArray[index];
        animalArray[index] = temp;
    }
    return animalArray;
}
const createLevel = () => {


    $canvas.innerHTML = '';
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    $canvas.dataset.answer =  animals[random];
    playSounds(animals[random]);

    const randomAnimals = shuffle(animals); // return array of shuffled animals
    randomAnimals.forEach((number) => {
        const liElement = document.createElement('li');
        liElement.innerText = number;
        liElement.dataset.id = number;
        $canvas.appendChild(liElement);
    });

    const playButton = document.createElement('li');
    playButton.classList.add('play-sound');
    playButton.dataset.id = 'play-sound';
    $canvas.appendChild(playButton);
}

createLevel();

$canvas.addEventListener('click', selectedAnswer);
```

I managed to put this code together by looking at a few different sites. so I am not sure how to make the conversion from emoji to images.

Or if someone has a better way, I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest as a first step to change animals to something more like this. Then you set the source of an [img html tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) to the image path.

```
  const animals = {
    dog : {
      sound: './sounds/dog.mp3',
      image: './images/dog.png',
      emoji: ''
    },
    cat: {
      sound: './sounds/cat.mp3',
      image: './images/cat.png',
      emoji: ''
    },
    gorilla: {
      sound: './sounds/gorilla.mp3',
      image: './images/gorilla.png',
      emoji: ''
    }
};
```